# How to use tab in disp()?

Tags: matlab, ascii, string-literals, disp

```
disp(['counter ' num2str(blk) (here I need a tab!!!) 'adc ' num2str(adc_nr)])
```

Comment: (This should have been tagged [tag:tab] and not [tag:tabs], which is about *"multiple user interface elements, e.g. browser tabs"*)

Comment: There is no tab-Tag.

Comment: the aliases must be acting weird. You can type 'tab' in the tag field and it's recognized as being distinct from 'tabs'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
disp(['counter ' num2str(blk) 9 'adc ' num2str(adc_nr)])
```

Explanation: Usually if you want to insert a tab, you put a '\t' in the string. This works well for `sprintf`, but the `disp` command doesn't interpret it properly. So one solution is to put the ASCII value of the tab directly, which is '9'.

Comment: ASCII 009, also written as \t in more user-friendly languages... It's really nasty to see a magic 9 inside a string display command.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is absolutely correct. However, here is a more readable way to do the same:

```matlab
disp("counter " + blk + char(9) + "adc " + adc_nr)
```

*Tried on MATLAB R2023a Update 2*